# Why is this app install failing as incompatible and can it be force installed?

Tags: installation, apk, compatibility, 7.1-nougat

I've used the Yell app for ages (com.yell.launcher2). It's recently updated and should be compatible with modern android (and is listed as compatible with 4+). I'm using LineageOS (=7.1) on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S7, which is certainly up to date. But the installer (when I open the APK) says it didn't install as it's incompatible, which surprises me.

Is there a log, or a way to tell, what the exact conflict is, either via GUI or terminal, and based on that information, is it likely that I can force it to install (perhaps it won't work once installed, but I suspect it will, but for sure it can't run if it doesn't get installed in the first place). If so what might work?

Answer (score 0):

Install this APK with `adb install` from your PC, or `pm install` from a terminal emulator on the phone. This will give you the reason of failure. Alternatively, you could also search through the log output of `adb logcat`, though this approach is more tedious.

Comment: `pm install` usually fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI`, though.